# Use the same route for url and for url with a trailing slash in sammy.js

Tags: javascript, url-routing, sammy.js

I am playing around with [sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) and I have a problem with a trailing slash in the end of the url. Here is an example:

I want my app to do a particular thing when the url looks like `#!users` and I can easily achieve this with the following code:

```
Sammy(function() {
    this.get('#!users', function(){
       console.log('users');
    });
}).run();
```

The problem is that I want it to behave the same way with `#!users/`. Assuming that I have a lot of such different urls I do not want to copy the code around, is there a way in sammy.js to handle in the same way `url` and `url/`?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and decided to fix it with a catch-all at the end of my Sammy set-up.  My solution removes the trailing slash if there is one:

```
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('#', function () {
        // ...
    });
    this.notFound = function (method, path) {
        if (path[path.length - 1] === '/') {
            // remove trailing slash
            window.location = path.substring(0, path.length - 1);
        } else {
            // redirect to not found
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading more carefully [documentation](http://sammyjs.org/docs) I have found a hack to do this (there is no specific method to have such behavior). So my way of doing this is:

```
Sammy(function() {
    this.get('#!users/?', function(){
        console.log('Users');
    });

    this.get('#!users/:id/?', function(){
        console.log('User with id ' + this.params.id);
    });
}).run();
```

So, all I need is to add `/?` in the end (which in regular expressions means one or 0 of /)